# Unable to discard changes in working directory

Tags: ruby, git

I have this file in working directory called Gemfile.lock. Basically, this file gets refreshed every time another file Gemfile gets modified. But I was able to

```
git stash
```

Gemfile but Gemfile.lock did not get put in stash. So then I tried

```
git checkout Gemfile.lock
```

and

```
git checkout -- Gemfile.lock
```

But everytime I run 'git status', it remains highlighted in red in the working directory. I do not want to add it to the staging area to be committed to my local repository and ultimately the remote repository. But I also want to

```
git checkout
```

to another branch. But this file being in the working directory is preventing me from switching branches. What can I do?

Keep in mind, I do not want to add this file to .gitignore and invoke '`git rm --cached <file-name>`', because I do want this file to be tracked in git. I just do not want my current revision to be tracked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a case where `spring` caused troubles. Never figured out what happened. Should you use `rails` with `spring`, then try `spring stop` first.

Comment: You are right, this worked) Apparently spring is constantly reading this file preventing git to checkout a previous version.